# How to create spacing in Gridview

Tags: qt, qml

I want to create a gridview in QML. Each cell consisted of one image above and text below. How can I setup space between each cell and each rows in Gridview

Comment: Try to use `cellWidth` and `cellHeight` properties.

Answer (score 4):

You can set spacing by using cellWidth and cellHeight properties. As far as I know, there's no other spacing property.

Refer, https://forum.qt.io/topic/19775/solved-qml-gridview-and-spacing-between-children/2 for more information.

Comment: Thannks for your suggestion. The cellHeight is internal height of cell. But I want to set the color plate between rows in gridview. I using a Rectangle in my delegate to set color, but it only draw until the last item in list. Is there any other solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You can set [GridView's cellWidth](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#cellWidth-prop) and [GridView's cellHeight](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#cellHeight-prop) to some value and then inside its [delegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#delegate-prop) `width` and `height` to `cellWidth-8` and `cellHeight-8` to get spacing.

Answer (score -1):

This code create gridview of available videos in specific URL and display them as Images and Title. You need to click on the Image in order to see the Video.

```
  MyGridView{

        id: GridImage
        y: 150
        height: 250
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop
        cellWidth: 250
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        delegate: VideoDelegate {
        image: app.fileNameToUrl(model.image)
        title:  model.name
        onClicked: stack.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("TutorialView.qml"), {model:app.videosForProduct(model.id), title:title})
        }
        model: app.userLibrary
    }
}
```